# C#, using cmd line args in another method

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code that take one command line argument.

In the main method, I have a bunch of lines to make sure the argument is an integer.

I want to access this value, in another method.

My current code is as such:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        if (args.Length > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) > 0)
        {
                int seedValue;
                seedValue = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0.");
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0:");
    }
    return seedValue;
}
```

But I get a compiling error saying seedValue does not exist in the current context. How can I access the variable from another method, without calling the other method directly within the if statement? I don't want to make my code too chained, by calling every method at the end of the other one.

Comment: you should define 'seedValue' before the try block

Comment: I get: used of an unassigned local variable.

Comment: In addition to the answer given, consider the advantage of using [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to validate the input, instead of raising an exception (which costs more)

Comment: Can that code even compile?  You are returning the value of `seedValue` from `Main` which has a return type of `void`, so I don't see how that can be your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are declared `seedValue` in one scope and attempting to access it in another.

Essentially a scope is determined by the `{` and `}` braces. In your case, you are defining the variable within the `try` scope and attempting to access it within the method scope.

To solve this problem, do something like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int seedValue = -1;  //Or some other particular number.
    try
    { 
        if (args.Length > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) > 0)
        {                
                seedValue = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0.");
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0:");
    }
    return seedValue;
}
```

Note though that your `Main` method is void, thus it should not be returning anything.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        int seedValue = -1;  //Or some other particular number. 
        if (args.Length > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) > 0)
        {                
                seedValue = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
                MyOtherMethod(seedValue);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0.");
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0:");
    }        
}
```

Alternatively:

```
int seedValue = -1;
if ((args.Length > 0) && (Int32.TryParse(args[0], out seedValue))
   return seedValue;
else
   throw ArgumentException(...);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. When I move the value declartion before try, I get this: Error 1 Since 'cell_autom.Program.Main(string[])' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: since Main(string[] args) is void it should not return anything

Comment: @FilipeTeles: That is because, as per my last line, you method should not be yielding any values. You would need to remove the `return seedValue` line.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without assigning it a value first? Because otherwise, even if someone passes a letter or anything as the command line argument, I'll get -1 as the seed value, and I want it to display the error message instead.

Comment: if (args.Length > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) > 0 && seedValue > 0)

Comment: @FilipeTeles: I've tried to update the code with something which is more likely to be used.

Comment: This is wrong: seedValue is still being declared in the wrong scope. It needs to be above the try block in order for it to be accessible for the return.

Comment: @DLCross: Thanks for letting me know I reverted it back.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the seed value in a private variable of class scope. Then you'll be able to use it anywhere throughout the class. Alternatively, you can declare a public/internal/protected property to change the access scope.

```
public class Program
{
    private int _seedValue = 0; //invalid seed value, judging from your messages

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Length > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) > 0)
            {
                _seedValue = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0.");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, use an integer greater than 0:");
        }
    }

    public void ProcessSeed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_seedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare seedValue above the try block:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int seedValue = 0;
    try
    {
```

If you don't want to assign it an initial value, you will need to throw in your else block instead of just outputting a message to the console.